# soapui-pro- change JDBC connection string dynamically

Tags: soapui

How can I change the JDBC connection string, user name and password dynamically in the soapui -pro command line ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use properties.  See here:
    [Working with SoapUI Properties](http://www.soapui.org/Functional-Testing/working-with-properties.html)

Note the last point on the page regarding the command line:

```
Now when you run the request, the property will automatically be replaced with its current    
value. To use a different value just change the endpoint in the UI, or from the command-
line you can use the -P option;

-PServiceEndoint=dev.eviware.com:8884

which would use the dev.eviware.com:8884 endpoint instead (entirely fictional).
```

Comment: This isn't a property. If you click on JDBC connections tab, you can see Connectionstring. This is what I want to change dynamically

Comment: I got to know from Smartbear that I can define a project-level custom property which I can use in the connection-string via property-expansion and override from the command-line with the -P argument. So you are correct in a way!